# Constructing and returning Julia types in C

Tags: c, julia

How would you construct and return a Julia `Expr`, say `:(x + 2)`, from a C function called with `ccall` from Julia, preferably so that it can be garbage collected by Julia?

Edit:

As an edit was suggested with some additional details, here they are. To begin with, the question is not to generate the `Expr` in one go, but rater to be able to construct arbitrary `Expr`s and the like incremenally, see below.

I need a parser for a project in Julia. The contents of the parser input is in part algebraic expressions, and I would like to have the equivalent Julia `Expr` for these in the end. As there seems to be no parser generators with Julia targets, I was thinking about making the parser in C++ (which is convenient since I need to use the same parser grammar for C++ code in the same project anyway), either with flex/bison or ANTLR. So the question is really how you build the AST in Julia from the C++ parser. I have some ideas for solving this:

1. Have a bunch of callbacks in Julia that the C++ code can call (e.g. push literal/add etc. for algebraic expressions) and that Julia manages the allocation of the AST nodes. Or maybe just calling into `Symbol()`, `Expr()` and so on, plus more specialized callbacks for structures specific to the problem. Even if I am very new to Julia, I think I could pull that off.
2. Let the C++ parser generate an AST of plain structs that the Julia code can traverse to build the equivalent Julia structures. A bit of a messy solution, but maybe.
3. Have the C++ code allocate and return the Julia AST directly, which I think, if it would be possible, amounts to an AST of `jl_type_t` and friends. The big question is how such a structure is constructed. I have not found any documentation except the .h files, which are not that well commented. And I also doubt that memory allocated in the C++ code can be freed (garbage collected) in Julia, and I wonder how you could solve that.

Comment: Perhaps more details would be helpful. If the C function can also call Julia functions, then can't you create a Julia `Expr` by calling `Expr()` function from within your C function? Is it not a solution?

Comment: @Hckr Yes, maybe, see the edits of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I think that going for strategy 1 as stated in the question is the easiest and most robust way to solve this. Strategy 2 is possible, but that involves having mirrored ASTs in C and Julia, which makes the solution harder to maintain. Strategy 3, if even possible, requires in-depth knowledge about how the Julia type system works under the hood, and essentially amounts to duplicating functionality from the Julia C source code.

The only (minor) nuisance with my solution is that I have not been able to get a pointer to vararg `Expr` using `@cfunction`. So in the context of algebraic expressions, you would need separate function pointers to construct unary and binary operations, for example. If anyone has more success with this, let me know.

## Code

### expr.c

```
// struct to gather neccessary callbacks
typedef struct {
  void* (*symbol_callback)(char const *); // Symbol(Cstring)
  void* (*int_callback)(int); // Int(Int) - boxing an int
  void* (*expr4_callback)(void *, void*, void*, void*); // Expr for binary op
} callbacks;

void *expr(callbacks *c) {
  return c->expr4_callback(
    c->symbol_callback("call"),
    c->symbol_callback("+"),
    c->symbol_callback("x"),
    c->int_callback(2)
  );
}
```

### Makefile

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-c -Wall -fPIC

SOURCES=expr.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

lib: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -fPIC -o libexpr.so $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm *.o *.so
```

### Test.jl

```
# define a proxy function for Symbol(::String) that does the conversion from
# a C byte string
symbol_proxy(name::Ptr{UInt8})::Symbol = Symbol(unsafe_string(name))

struct Callbacks
    # pointer to Symbol(::String) proxy
    symbol::Ptr{Nothing}
    # pointer to Int(::Int) function
    int64::Ptr{Nothing}
    # pointer to Expr() function with four arguments (for binary op)
    expr4::Ptr{Nothing}
end

# get callbacks
c = Callbacks(
    @cfunction(symbol_proxy, Ref{Symbol}, (Ptr{UInt8},)),
    @cfunction(Int, Ref{Int64}, (Cint,)),
    @cfunction(Expr, Ref{Expr}, (Any,Any,Any,Any))
)

# call shared library to construct :(x+2)
e = ccall((:expr, "./libexpr"), Ref{Expr}, (Ref{Callbacks},), c)
dump(e)
```

## Output

Compiling the shared library with `make lib` and running `Test.jl` produces the output

```
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol +
    2: Symbol x
    3: Int64 2
```